# How to properly use custom image in VSCode remote containers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to use a VSCode Remote Container. I have decided **not** to base my container on one of the official Microsoft images available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers) instead it is based on the `epitechcontent/epitest-docker` docker image.

I am using the following configuration for the container so far:

`.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`

```json
{
    "name": "Babel",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
        "--security-opt",
        "seccomp=unconfined"
    ],
    "extensions": [
        "ms-vscode.cpptools",
        "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
        "twxs.cmake"
    ],
    "remoteUser": "babel",
    "workspaceMount": "type=bind,source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/home/babel"
}
```

`.devcontainer/Dockerfile`

```
# Using the latest epitech image
FROM epitechcontent/epitest-docker

# Setup a custom user with similar permissions
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/babel -s /bin/zsh -g root -G root -u 1001 babel

# Configure our workspace
WORKDIR /home/babel
RUN touch dummyfile
```

I am currently running into the following problems.

#### Container user permissions

It appears Microsoft VSCode Remote Containers create a default non-root user called `vscode` for all containers. As I'm not using the Microsoft images I'm looking for a way to create a user **with the same permissions as my session so that files created in the container are identical to those created outside the container by my regular user.**

To achieve this I'm creating a new user in the Dockerfile and I'm also setting the `remoteUser` property in the `devcontainer.json` to that very user.

What happens next is when I try to create a file inside the remote container it has different permissions than my regular session.

```
inside-the-container-shell> ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 babel root     14 Sep 22 16:59 file-created-outside-container
-rw-r--r-- 1 babel root      0 Sep 22 19:27 file-created-inside-container
```

#### Workspace and mount location

Inside the `Dockerfile` I set my user's home directory to `/home/babel` and I set the `WORKDIR` to `/home/babel` as well. In addition, inside `devcontainer.json` I'm setting `workspaceMount` to `type=bind,source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/home/babel` so the container is mounted in the home directory of the user.

Unfortunately this overrides the `dummyfile` that was `touch`ed during the building stage (cf the `Dockerfile`).

### Conclusion

I'm having a hard time finding good resources to learn how to use VSCode Remote Containers without the Microsoft images.

I'm trying to find a good way to declare a custom user much like the Microsoft images do.

I'm trying to find a way to not override the files that are here before the mount takes place.

Comment: Did you manage to create own docker image? I am curious. Can you share the results?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question @Pierwiastek, are you asking if I managed to run a VSCode remote container with a custom built image? If so yes, and I'm happy to share the configuration with you. If you meant something else, let me know.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am interested if you managed to run a VSCode remote container build on custom image, I would be very grateful for sharing the Dockerfile or any hints :)

Comment: Sure @Pierwiastek ! [Here](https://gist.github.com/rojas-diego/fa3dd471db6275c387a5473fbf28e19d) is a link to a Github Gist which does this. It's from 10 months ago, I don't remember much of it but I hope it's what you're searching for.

Comment: @DiegoROJAS - Have you find some documentation or reference for help?